# JPA @Column annotation to create comment/description

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I was wondering is it possible to create from jpa/hibernate annotation a database column description/comment like this:

`ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE status status INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'sample description/comment';`

It will be great functionality, but I cant find anything about this in JPA specification.

Maybe I should use `@Column(columnDefinition="")` property, but I dont have any clue.
Please help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found answer for my own question.

I am not sure is it ok? Will it work for all Databases?

For sure **it works for mysql**.

Here is the working code:

```
@Column(columnDefinition=" INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '0 for no action, 1 for executed, 2 for validated, 3 for aproved'")
private int status;
```

Comment: it attaches the given text to creation statements, so it works as long as the columnDefinition matches the underlying DB

Comment: Since not all RDBMS support "COMMENT" against a COLUMN (Postgresql, HSQLDB, Derby to name but some) then no this most certainly will only work for a very limited set of RDBMS. Additionally, putting it in an annotation means the compiled code is tied to those RDBMS that allow that syntax, whereas if you'd put it in an XML file you could swap out orm.xml file based on the RDBMS being used.

Comment: Yes. I agree with You Guys. But couldn't find better solution. What do You mean by XML?

Comment: Is it possible for Table?

Comment: I think I would work also with `@Table` annotation, but have not tested.

Comment: What is the equivalent of columnDefinition in @Table. Can't make it out...

Comment: I used JPA javax.persistence.Table in org.hibernate.annotations.Table it exists.

Comment: I've not find any info about @Table support for commentary, but IMHO I would avoid this approach as possible. I think that You aren't the first person who need do something like that, but if there is no support for that, there should be a better solution/approach for that.

Answer (score 7):

Comment description already exists for **Table annotations**. We must use the Hibernate @Table annotation for that, complementary with the JPA @Table annotation.

For example :

```
@javax.persistence.Table( name = "Cat" )
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table( comment = "Table for cats" )
public class Cat {
...
```

Concerning the column's comment :
It seems there is no equivalent, even in Hibernate 5.2 / JPA 2.1.

There has been an issue submitted a long time ago (2007) on this subject, but still unresolved : [Support @Comment or column attribute on @Table and @Column](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4369). Abandoned since 2012 ?

I also found comment use in *org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect* :

```
/**
 * Does this dialect/database support commenting on tables, columns, etc?
 *
 * @return {@code true} if commenting is supported
 */
public boolean supportsCommentOn() {
    return false;
}

/**
 * Get the comment into a form supported for table definition.
 *
 * @param comment The comment to apply
 *
 * @return The comment fragment
 */
public String getTableComment(String comment) {
    return "";
}

/**
 * Get the comment into a form supported for column definition.
 *
 * @param comment The comment to apply
 *
 * @return The comment fragment
 */
public String getColumnComment(String comment) {
    return "";
}
```

For example PostgreSQL81Dialect supports it (supportsCommentOn() returns true).

It enables the use of the SQL command "COMMENT ON ...",
like in PostgreSQL (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-comment.html).
For example :

```
COMMENT ON TABLE my_schema.my_table IS 'Employee Information';
COMMENT ON COLUMN my_table.my_column IS 'Employee ID number';
```

It seems to be used there : *org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.StandardTableExporter#getSqlCreateStrings*

The column's comment is extracted from the Hibernate Mapping with *org.hibernate.mapping.Column#getComment*.

Finally, If using **Hibernate Tools** and reverse engineering, the column's comment is extracted from JDBC DatabaseMetaData, with *org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.BasicColumnProcessor#processBasicColumns*.

```
-> String comment = (String) columnRs.get("REMARKS");
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `@Comment` annotation.

This annotation is introduced in `hibernate 5.6.0` version(released at 2021-09-21), and `Spring Boot 2.6`(released at 2021-11-17) is using Hibernate 5.6

[https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4369\](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4369%5C)
https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/3611

```java
@Entity(name = "Person")
@javax.persistence.Table(name = TABLE_NAME)
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(comment = TABLE_COMMENT, appliesTo = TABLE_NAME)
public static class TestEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Comment("I am id")
    private Long id;

    @Comment("I am name")
    @javax.persistence.Column(length = 50)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "other")
    @Comment("I am other")
    private TestEntity other;

}
```

Comment: Problem with this is, it's not JPA. So when you are using IntelliJ assistance to generate the DDL it won't include the Hibernate specific annotations

Answer (score 2):

While Hibernate mappings are needed for mapping Domain Models to Relational Data, it's not a good idea to stretch this feature to generating the database schema too.

This might work for a relatively small project, but when you have a medium to large enterprise application, that evolves with every Sprint iteration, you then need a database schema migration tool, like [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/).

The comment doesn't require a Domain Model mapping, since it's a relational specific description. The Domain Model should make use JavaDocs to document each field meaning (according to a specific domain logic requirement).

Comment: It should be noted that you should keep your DB schema and generated model in sync. Otherwise you'll get in trouble sooner or later when something differs. I usually have automated tests that compare the migrated (using flyway as noted) and the generated schemas.

Comment: Do you verify schema against development environment? That mostly have no sense. DBA may do changes on production server that break your tested migration scripts )) I ask for production  DDL, applied it in development environment and tested against it.

Comment: Of course it makes sense. This way you can store all schema changes in Git and the DBA can just add a new script there also. Manually adding changes to the DB is like injecting modified classes in your application jars in production.